# IndexOutOfRangeException on multidimensional array despite using GetLength check

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, indexoutofrangeexception

I am using the following code to read values from an Excel spreadsheet:

```
// Start with passed
int lastPassRow = sheets[passedVehicles].GetLength(0);

for (int i = 1; i < lastPassRow; i++)
{
   // Exception here
   if(DateTime.TryParse(sheets[passedVehicles][i, 0].ToString(), out result))
   {
      passedDates.Add((DateTime)sheets[passedVehicles][i, 0]);
   }
}
```

The type of `sheets[passedVehicles]` is a multidimensional array of `Object[,]` and the for loop above is giving me an `IndexOutOfRange` exception at i = 1, despite that I check the number of rows.

I added some logging for the spreadsheet in question, and have verified:

- i = 1 is the iteration that is failing
- The value of `lastPassRow` is 4
- The value of `sheets[passedVehicles].GetLength(1)` is also four.

All values appear to be in range to me. Is there something else that could cause this exception?

Note: I am starting at i = 1 because row 0 is a header in the spreadsheet and does not contain data I am trying to read.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `sheets[passedVehicles][0, i]`?

Comment: @Kryptos No, I've always used the `[row, column]` convention and it has worked for everything except this.

Comment: What if you evaluate `sheets[passedVehicles].GetLowerBound(0)` and the same for `1`? Excel arrays are 1-based, not 0-based, so it could have a lower bound of `1` rather than `0`. C# arrays are always 0-based, but the more generic `Array` class actually allows for arbitrary lower and upper bounds.

Comment: Ok then try `sheets[passedVehicles][i, 1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it's the `0` that's out of range.

Excel arrays are 1-based, not 0-based as you might expect.

Comment: You're absolutely right. No more exception! I didn't read the right data, I suspect because of an error in my LINQ statement. I'm gonna try and verify that it's a separate issue, and as long as that's the case I'll come back and accept this. Great catch!