# Non-0 based arrays in C# with traditional [ ] array syntax?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'd like to be able to create an array in C# with an arbitrary range of index bounds, e.g., a 16 element array with indices of 100-115.

Native arrays in C# are 0-based, but I'm told (e.g., in Luaan's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327476/indexoutofrangeexception-on-multidimensional-array-despite-using-getlength-check)), that the C# Array class allows arbitrary lower and upper bounds.  But in the examples I've seen elements in the Array class are accessed via myArray.*GetValue()* and myArray.*SetValue()* instead of conventional array syntax like myArray **[** foo **]**.

```
Array arr = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), new[]{16}, new[]{100});
Console.WriteLine(arr.Length); // 16
arr.SetValue("foo", 100);
Console.WriteLine(arr.GetValue(100)); // foo
```

Is there any way to make an array with some arbitrary starting index, like [100] that I can access with traditional [ ] syntax in C#?

Comment: Are you looking for [indexers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), or had you already ruled those out somehow?

Comment: why do you need this? no offense, but this sounds like a super bad idea.

Comment: I honestly can't think of a case where you would need to do this...

Comment: @ O. R. Mapper I get that indexers allow me to add array-like access to arbitrary classes, but how do they let me set arbitrary array bounds (e.g., 100-115 instead of 0-15)

Comment: Will `Dictionary<int, string>` work for you? After making an instance of it, you can add items like `dict.Add(100, "Hello")` and access it by `dict[100]` (gives " Hello").

Comment: What is so important about indices 100-115? Could you not just create a 16 element array and subtract 100 from where ever 100-115 come from to propagate the 0-based array?

Comment: @user316117: Lukas provides a code sample showing how they could let you create an offset array. For an arbitrary offset, simply replace the hard-coded `1` in his code with a field that gets set from a constructor parameter.

Comment: @Tdorno The reasons why we want to do this are beyond the scope of this question but briefly we're controlling a bank of industrial machines (1-32) where each one is associated with a several matching banks of other industrial machines, and from a debugging and code-readability, and especially trace-dump-readability standpoint it would be convenient to be able to reference a matching configuration could be represented as [7], [107] and [207]

Comment: @user316117 Lukas is the guy who wrote an answer for you. You really should sub-class all of this.

Comment: @user316117: What your actual goal is can be very much in scope. This sounds like an X/Y problem and if you included more about what you are trying to achieve, you could get better suggestions on how to tackle it. With what you've provided, it sounds like a `Dictionary<int, string>` might actually be more appropriate as Sjips suggested. A `Dictionary<int,T>` works quite well as a kind of sparse array. Especially if the order of indexes isn't important.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class that implements the decorator pattern: just implement the IList interface (wich is also implemented by Array) and do whatever shifting you want on the this [int index] property.

The decorator pattern is described here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479635/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusDecoratorp

Answer (score 2):

The Array class does not support this, but you can write your own array class with one-based indices:

```
public class OneBasedArray<T>
{
    public T[] InnerArray;
    public T this[int i]
    {
        get { return InnerArray[i-1]; }
        set { InnerArray[i-1] = value; }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var myArray = new OneBasedArray<int> { InnerArray = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } };
for(int i = 1; i <=5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myArray[i]);
}
```

This code is only to get the idea, such a class would of course need a nicer interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use an array's indexer when it's a 0-indexed array.

You can use an indexer for a custom, non-array, type, and use whatever logic you want for it, such as making it non-zero-indexed, but that's not an option for arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I think Lukas' answer is probably the easiest way to handle this, but if, for some reason, you really wanted to use `Array.CreateInstance` (not sure why you would - maybe some external library might insist on it?), you could wrap it in a class like this:

```
public class NonZeroArray<T>
{
    private readonly Array array;

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get { return (T)array.GetValue(i); }
        set { array.SetValue(value, i); }
    }

    public NonZeroArray(int length, int lowerBounds = 0)
    {
        array = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new int[] { length}, new int[] { lowerBounds } );
    }
}
```

You could obviously make this a lot prettier (and easier to work with) by having it implement the rest of `IList<T>`. And if you *really* need the native array, you could implement a property with a getter to expose it when needed.

Using it would be simply:

```
var myNonZeroArray = new NonZeroArray<string>(16,100);
myNonZeroArray[100] = "foo";
Console.WriteLine(myNonZeroArray[100]);   // prints "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a custom class that extends `IList<T>` to provide functionality for starting at a non-zero index:

```
public class NonZeroList<T> : IList<T>
{
    private int startIndex;
    private List<T> inner;

    public NonZeroList(int startIndex, IEnumerable<T> content)
    {
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        inner = content.ToList();
    }
    public NonZeroList(int startIndex)
    {
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        inner = new List<T>();
    }

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return inner[i - startIndex];
        }
        set
        {
            inner[i - startIndex] = value;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (T i in inner)
            yield return i;
        yield break;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return inner.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return inner.IndexOf(item) + startIndex;
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        inner.Insert(index - startIndex, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        inner.RemoveAt(index - startIndex);
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        inner.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        inner.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return inner.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        inner.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return inner.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return inner.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

To use it, you initialize it just as you would a normal `List<T>`, but with the start index specified (e.g. `NonZeroList<int> myList = new NonZeroList<int>(20) { 0, 1, 2, 3 };`). You can then use it just as you would a normal `List<T>` or `T[]`.

If you want to use it as an array instead of a list, then you can simply add bounds checking or implement `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IList<T>`, and create utility functions yourself.